# Kali Linux Live USB: Flashing _ on boot-up

Tags: boot, usb-flash-drive, livecd, kali-linux

I have installed Kali Linux onto a Live USB using

```
dd if=kali.iso of=/dev/sdb1
```

However, upon boot it just has a flashing _ in the top left corner...

Comment: 1. At the official documentation `dd if=kali.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=512k` 
2. you sure you used the correct 32/64bit iso?
3. Is your BIOS set to boot from USB?

Comment: I have got the correct ISO file and yes, it is set to boot from USB...

Comment: I've run into this situation 2 times before, once on a dual-boot, the more recent one on a VM. Try reinstalling it, it worked for me. Also if that doesn't work try 1.0.7 http://superuser.com/questions/818067/kali-installation-error

Comment: I've tried reinstalling so I'll try 1.0.7... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're on a UNIX system, because you can use dd, so, if you are on Linux, the command should be:

`dd if=kali.iso of=/dev/sdb1 bs=512k`

For Mac:

`dd if=kali.iso of=/dev/sdb1 bs=1m`

You may have a corrupted flash drive from the block size not being right. Another note, you have to make sure that your flash drive is BIOS and not an EFI boot. If you have BIOS, make a BIOS bootable. if your flash drive is EFI make sure your system is.